# Медленный запрос count(*)

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, count

Я решил немного поиграться с относительно большими объемами данных. Создал простую базу данных из двух таблиц и написал для нее программку, которая заполнила её данными. 
Первая вот такая:

```
CREATE TABLE Cities
(
    Id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    Name nvarchar(50) NULL
)
```

Она содержит 100 строк.
Вторая, главная:

```
CREATE TABLE People
(
    Id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    CityId int NOT NULL,
    Name nvarchar(50) NULL,
    LastName nvarchar(50) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT People_Id_Idx PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id ASC)
)

ALTER TABLE People  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT fk_cities 
FOREIGN KEY(CityId) REFERENCES Cities (Id)
```

Она содержит 100 миллионов строк. Люди распределены по городам равномерно. 
Так вот вопрос. Когда я пишу очень простой запрос:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) -- COUNT(Id) даёт такой же результат
FROM People
```

то он отрабатывает очень долго (около 100-130 секунд). Я конечно понимаю, что 100 миллионов записей - это довольно много, но всё-таки полторы-две минуты на такой запрос это очень много. Тем более, что необходимость узнать количество записей в таблице возникает довольно часто. Тем более, что сто миллионов записей - это совсем не предел. Ведь какие-нибудь банки ворочают таблицами с куда большим числом записей и столбцов. Как вообще они борются за производительность?

Дополнительный данные:

- Версия sql-сервер: 
  Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Enterprise Edition (64-bit)
- План запроса: 
  [image: План запроса]

Comment: Можно хранить агрегаты. Например, добавили строку +1, удалили -1.

Comment: Посмотрите этот ответ http://stackoverflow.com/a/12480084/1775065

Comment: Банки не считают количество всех записей в таблице на частой основе. Кроме того, стоит проверить, не читался ли индекс с диска.

Answer (score 18):

Ок, сначала стоит выяснить почему именно тормозит ваш запрос.

Я вбил в таблицу 100 млн записей. Запустил count с измерением времени (с отключенным Show Actual Execution Plan - эта опция влияет на результаты измерений!):

```
set statistics io on
set statistics time on
select count(*) from People

Table 'People'. Scan count 9, logical reads 942693, physical reads 0, 
   read-ahead reads 18, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, 
   lob read-ahead reads 0.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 8064 ms,  elapsed time = 1169 ms.
```

Запрос выполнился чуть больше чем за секунду. План выполнения, если его просмотреть, совпадает с вашим:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что плохо в таком плане выполнения, и почему запрос отработал быстро на моей машине, но медленно - на вашей?

В вашей таблице есть кластерный индекс (это хорошо). Что такое кластерный индекс? Это большое дерево поиска, состоящие из 8-килобайтных страниц (BTree, прошитое по уровням), в листьях которого хранятся данные записей.

Как SQL сервер считает count(*) без условия? Он считает количество записей в Primary Key. Делает он это, проходя по нижнему уровню (листьям) дерева и подсчитывая количество записей в каждой странице.

Каждое обращение к странице, которая уже находится в памяти - это logical read. Как видите, SQL Server-у пришлось перебрать 942693*8 = примерно 7.5Gb данных ради подсчета количества строк. Это не сверхстрашно, но только в случае, когда данные таблицы уже оказались в памяти. В моем случае они лежали в памяти только потому, что SQL Server только что вставил данные в эту таблицу, и решил пока не сбрасывать кэш.

Что происходит, если страницы, из которой нужно прочитать, в памяти не оказывается? Например, когда у вас просто мало оперативной памяти, и база не влазит в ее целиком. Тогда logical read превращается в physical read - реальное чтение с диска. И вы получаете:

Table 'People'. Scan count 9, logical reads 942693, physical reads 942693...

SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = ??? ms,  elapsed time = 100000 ms (условно)

Потому что SQL Server пытается читать с диска в 4/8/?? потоков, а даже линейное чтение 7.5Gb с диска по 100Mb/s дает вам задержку в 76.8 секунд (судя по скорости чтения - у вас HDD, а не SSD). Потери на нелинейность и одновременность (HDD это очень не любят) - и вот ваши 130 секунд в результате.

Что можно сделать:

1. Поставить больше памяти (ее никогда не бывает много!)
2. Поставить SSD (значительно смягчит проблему)
3. Заставить SQL Server читать меньше данных при подсчете count. Например, создать дополнительный некластерный индекс, в котором будут только ID:

   ```
   CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [People_Id_Only] ON [dbo].[People]
   (
       [Id] ASC
   )
   ```

   ... и SQL Server начнет использовать его для подсчета количества строк:

   ```
   Table 'People'. Scan count 9, logical reads 125415,
   ```

   Всего прочитанных 979 мегабайт на 10 млн записей - не так уж и плохо!
4. Использовать материализованные представления (Indexed Views) - оптимальный вариант. Хорошо расписан в [ответе от i-one](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/606969/177221), **я бы предложил вам выбрать именно это решение**.

Стоит отметить, что решения с индексами (3 и 4) не бесплатны с точки зрения поддержки. Индексы требуют расходов на хранение (особенно видно в (3)) и на поддержание их в актульном состоянии (что чуть-чуть увеличивает время вставки записи). Решение на indexed view так же заметно усложняет план вставки каждой записи. Не удивляйтесь, если обнаружите что простая вставка

```
insert into People (CityId, Name, LastName)
values (1, 'test', 'one')
```

начнет выполняться вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Процентам в плане слишком сильно верить нельзя, но стоит обращать на них внимание. Хорошо видно что решения (3) и (4) совсем не бесплатны.

---

Кроме того, индексы обычно решают проблемы конкретных запросов. Например, созданный в (3) индекс будет неприменим при группировке по городам. А индекс с группировкой по городам может оказаться неэффективен при группировке по другому полю. Иногда наличие индекса может значительно ухудшить результат (например, в случае update на базе сложной выборке).

Стоит всегда измерять результат до и после оптимизации, и не забывать, что индекс может повлиять не только на тот запрос, который вы оптимизировали, но и на те запросы, что вы трогать не собирались.

Comment: Не надо триггер! Индексированное представление прекрасно справится с этой задачей.

Comment: @PavelMayorov согласен. вычеркнул триггеры, они для слабаков . Я бы на месте топикастера выбрал ответ от i-one.

Comment: @PavelMayorov дописал про цену использования  индексов и indexed views - на всякий случай.

Comment: там накладные расходы намного меньше чем у обычного индекса. Потому что это, по-сути, тоже индекс - только очень маленький.

Comment: @PavelMayorov меньше расходы на хранение, но больше расходы CPU и памяти на обновление view при вставке. На моих тестовых данных из ответа - вставка в таблицу без index view - 4 logical reads. Вставка с indexed view - 22 logical reads (из них 12 - из-за Table Spool). План для вставки 3 строк - выдает 42 reads с двумя сортировками. Да еще и обновление indexed views идет через sequence, по одному - так что ими легко убить производительность insert/update :(

Answer (score 7):

Если `COUNT` нужен в целях оценки, то, как верно отметили в комментариях, проще всего обратиться к DMV. Например к `sys.dm_db_partition_stats`:

```sql
select sum(row_count)
from sys.dm_db_partition_stats
where object_id = object_id('People') and index_id in (0, 1);
```

это даст приблизительное число строк в таблице (иногда точное, но точность не гарантируется).

Если нужно точное число строк в таблице, то придётся честно выполнить запрос `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM People`. В ответе участника [PashaPash](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/177221/pashapash) хорошо описаны причины, по которым такой запрос может быть медленным и способы устранения. Мне также нравится ответ участника [MaxU](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/211923/maxu). Я бы использовал этот подход, только оформил бы это в виде материализованного представления:

```sql
create view mvPeopleCityCnt
with schemabinding
as
    select CityId, Cnt = count_big(*)
    from dbo.People
    group by CityId;
GO
create unique clustered index mvPeopleCityCnt_Pk on mvPeopleCityCnt (CityId);
GO
```

Отмечу, что можно было бы материализовать запрос `select count_big(*) from People` (не делая группировку по `CityId`). Учитывая, однако, что число городов относительно небольшое, материализация с группировкой по `CityId` может быть выгоднее, т.к. в этом случае в дополнение к запросу

```sql
select count(*)
from People;
```

обращением к индексу `mvPeopleCityCnt_Pk` также могут быть удовлетворены, например, и такие запросы:

```sql
select CityId, count(*)
from People
group by CityId;

select distinct CityId
from People;
```

При их выполнении в случае наличия материализованного представления, SqlServer обратится к нему, а не к таблице People.

Ниже сравнение производительности запроса `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM People` для четырёх разных подходов:

```
clustered index (Id):
Table 'People'. Scan count 5, logical reads 1290799 ...
CPU time = 7333 ms,  elapsed time = 2051 ms.

nonclustered index (Id):
Table 'People'. Scan count 5, logical reads 124188 ...
CPU time = 6911 ms,  elapsed time = 1840 ms.

nonclustered columnstored index (Id):
Table 'People'. Scan count 4, ..., lob logical reads 116054 ...
CPU time = 999 ms,  elapsed time = 252 ms.

materialized view:
Table 'mvPeopleCityCnt'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2 ...
CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
```

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю в данном случае надо каким-то образом кешировать уже агрерированные данные.

Один из вариантов создать таблицу:

```
CREATE TABLE CityStats(
    CityId      int,
    Population  int,
    CONSTRAINT CityStats_CityId_Idx PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (CityId ASC)
);
```

и обновлять (поддерживать) ее тригером на `People`...

Comment: Не надо триггер! Индексированное представление прекрасно справится с этой задачей.

Answer (score 1):

Если надо быстро посмотреть количество строк в таблице, то можно воспользоваться хранимкой sp_spaceused

```
EXEC sys.sp_spaceused @objname = N'People'
```

Второй столбец в результате - "rows" - и будет количеством строк в таблице на текущий момент.

Comment: она выводит сумму `row_count` из `sys.dm_db_partition_stats` - это приблизительный результат, а не точное количество строк

Answer (score 1):

Количество строк можно узнать из системного представления [dm_db_partition_stats](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-partition-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) по кластерному индексу:

```
SELECT SUM(s.row_count)
FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats s
WHERE s.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID('схема.таблица')
    AND s.index_id < 2;
```

Также если неожиданно стал тормозить запрос типа:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM схема.таблица;
```

, то возможно стоит обновить метаданные по этой таблице с помощью команды [UPDATEUSAGE](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-updateusage-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
DBCC UPDATEUSAGE(БД, 'схема.таблица') WITH COUNT_ROWS;
```

Более детально обсуждалось [здесь](https://m.habr.com/ru/post/271797/)

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Спасибо за уточнение-сегодня добавлю развернутый ответ

Answer (score 0):

Узнавать число строк в таблице не имеет смысла - это число может устареть в следующий же момент. Если только вы не повесите блокировку на всю таблицу целиком.  Если у вас такая необходимость возникает довольно часто - вы что-то делаете не так.

Для диагностики можете взять какое-нибудь приближенное решение отсюда: https://habrahabr.ru/post/271797/

А если по какой-то причине нужны точные данные, в любой момент и быстро - можно воспользоваться индексированным представлением:

```
create view PeopleCount with schemabinding 
as select count_big(*) as [count] from dbo.People
go

create unique clustered index PK_PeopleCount ON PeopleCount([count])
```

Использование:

- на младших редакциях SQL Server: `select [count] from PeopleCount with (noexpand)`
- на старших редакциях SQL Server можно сделать и так: `select count(*) from People`

Answer (score -2):

Попробуй сделать индекс по People.ID

```
Id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
```

У таблицы People нет первичного ключа и поиск ведётся перебором всех записей.

Детально проблему покажет

```
explain select count(*) from people;
```

Comment: Это sql server, картинка в вопросе - это и есть местный explain

Comment: И кластерный индекс по id тоже есть - в конце объявления таблицы

Comment: @Сергей Келер индекс там разумеется есть. Это первичный ключ и там по умолчанию создан кластерный индекс